# How to create list of objects in JSON for every class field in Java

Tags: java, json

I can have generic objects as a field of one of my classes f.e.

```
public class Class1<T> {
   List<T> genericObjects;
}
```

and this objects can look like that:

```
private int id;
private String name;
```

or like that:

```
private int id;
private int childId;
```

I need to send a JSON, that contains a list of properties and every property should be presented as an object.

So it should look like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "name"
    }
]
```

and so on. Is there a way to implement that cleanly for objects that are generic and can contain one or more different properties? And for normal, not generic class?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@JsonTypeInfo
```

As I did here (Note that I omitted the required getters ans setters) :

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Class1<A> a = new Class1<>();
        a.genericObjects = Collections.singletonList(new A(1, "A"));

        Class1<B> b = new Class1<>();
        b.genericObjects = Collections.singletonList(new B(2, "B"));

        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(a));
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(b));
    }

}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
class Class1<T> {
    List<T> genericObjects;
}

class A {

    int id;
    String name;

    A(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B {

    int id;
    String childId;

    B(int id, String childId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.childId = childId;
    }
}
```

There are various usages of the `@JsonTypeInfo'. I chose the`class approch` which adds a special identifier '@class' with the concrete class full name to each element in the array.

Comment: thank you for this anwer! I will try to use this solution and of course inform about results

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
public class AppGsonBuilder {

    public static GsonBuilder jsonObjectBuilder(){
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JsonObject.class, new JsonSerializer<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(JsonObject src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                         JsonSerializationContext context) {
                if (src == null) {
                    return new JsonPrimitive("");
                } else {
                    return src;
                }
            }
        });
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JsonObject.class, new JsonDeserializer<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public JsonObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                if(!json.isJsonObject()){
                    return new JsonObject();
                }
                return json.getAsJsonObject();
            }
        });

        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JsonArray.class, new JsonSerializer<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(JsonArray src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                         JsonSerializationContext context) {
                if (src == null) {
                    return new JsonPrimitive("");
                } else {
                    return src;
                }
            }
        });
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JsonArray.class, new JsonDeserializer<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
            public JsonArray deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                if(!json.isJsonArray()){
                    return new JsonArray();
                }
                return json.getAsJsonArray();
            }
        });

        return gsonBuilder;
    }
}

AppGsonBuilder.jsonObjectBuilder().create().toJson("any json string")
```

Comment: Please add some more info on how it will be helpful to an author of this question.

Comment: you can user JsonObject as your generic class, and user this TypeAdapter to serializable  or deserialize jsons

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    yourList.stream().forEach(object -> {
        try {
            String writeValueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(writeValueAsString);
            JSONArray arrya = new JSONArray();
            Iterator keys = json.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()){
                String next = (String)keys.next();
                arrya.put(new JSONObject().put(next, json.get(next)));
            }
        System.out.println("==>"+arrya);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```